# How to display all messages (success, error, notice, warning) on top of the page in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, messages

Presently on my site all messages showing on middle of the page but want to display all messages on top of the page. any idea? please share.

'

```
<?php
global $var_yttheme;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>

<?php 
    if( $var_yttheme->getParam('usebgimage') == 1 && $var_yttheme->getParam('usecustomizeimage') == 0 ){
        $bg_image = $var_yttheme->getParam('bgimage');
    }else{
        $bg_image = '';
    }

    $hdStyles = $var_yttheme->getParam('headerstyles');
    $classHeader = "";
    $classHome = "";
    if($hdStyles == 'header1'){
         $classHeader = "header1-wrap";  
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header2') {
        $classHeader = "header2-wrap";
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header3') {
        $classHeader = "header3-wrap";
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header4') {
        $classHeader = "header4-wrap"; 
    }

    if( Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home-v4'  && 
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' ) {
        $classHome = "homepagev4";
    }

?>

<body id="bd" class="<?php echo $var_yttheme->template ?> <?php echo $bg_image;?> <?php if( $var_yttheme->getParam('layoutstyle') == '2' ){echo "layout-boxed";}?> <?php echo $this->getBodyClass();?> <?php echo $classHome;?>">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <div id="yt_wrapper">

        <!-- BEGIN: Header -->
        <div id="yt_header" class="yt-header wrap <?php echo $classHeader; ?>">         
             <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END: Header -->

        <!-- BEGIN: content -->        
        <div id="yt_content" class="yt-content wrap">

            <div id="yt_main" class="yt-main col-main">
                <div class="yt-main-inner yt-content-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class ="row">                    
                            <?php if($this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs')){ ?>          
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <div class="columns-w">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>

                            <?php if( $this->getChildHtml('banner-top-home') ){?>                   
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('banner-top-home');?>                            
                            <?php }?>

                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                    <!-- Hot categories home page -->
                    <?php if( $this->getChildHtml('hot-categories') ){?>
                        <div class="hotcate-wrap">
                            <div class="container">
                            <div class ="row">                  
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('hot-categories');?> 
                            </div>
                            </div>                      
                        </div>
                    <?php }?>                    
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>      
        <!-- END: content -->

        <!-- BEGIN: footer -->
        <div id="yt_footer" class="yt-footer wrap">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END: footer -->
        <?php 
        if( Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home'  && 
                        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' && $var_yttheme->getParam('showPopup') == 1  ) { 
        ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('popup_location') ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

'

this is my 1column.phtml file please edit your answer in this file.

"updated file is,"

app\design\frontend\mypackage\mytheme\template\page\1column.phtml

'

```
<?php
global $var_yttheme;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>

<?php 
    if( $var_yttheme->getParam('usebgimage') == 1 && $var_yttheme->getParam('usecustomizeimage') == 0 ){
        $bg_image = $var_yttheme->getParam('bgimage');
    }else{
        $bg_image = '';
    }

    $hdStyles = $var_yttheme->getParam('headerstyles');
    $classHeader = "";
    $classHome = "";
    if($hdStyles == 'header1'){
         $classHeader = "header1-wrap";  
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header2') {
        $classHeader = "header2-wrap";
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header3') {
        $classHeader = "header3-wrap";
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header4') {
        $classHeader = "header4-wrap"; 
    }

    if( Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home-v4'  && 
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' ) {
        $classHome = "homepagev4";
    }

?>

<body id="bd" class="<?php echo $var_yttheme->template ?> <?php echo $bg_image;?> <?php if( $var_yttheme->getParam('layoutstyle') == '2' ){echo "layout-boxed";}?> <?php echo $this->getBodyClass();?> <?php echo $classHome;?>">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <div id="yt_wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
        <!-- BEGIN: Header -->
        <div id="yt_header" class="yt-header wrap <?php echo $classHeader; ?>">         
             <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END: Header -->

        <!-- BEGIN: content -->        
        <div id="yt_content" class="yt-content wrap">

            <div id="yt_main" class="yt-main col-main">
                <div class="yt-main-inner yt-content-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class ="row">                    
                            <?php if($this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs')){ ?>          
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <div class="columns-w">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>


                            <?php if( $this->getChildHtml('banner-top-home') ){?>                   
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('banner-top-home');?>                            
                            <?php }?>

                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                    <!-- Hot categories home page -->
                    <?php if( $this->getChildHtml('hot-categories') ){?>
                        <div class="hotcate-wrap">
                            <div class="container">
                            <div class ="row">                  
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('hot-categories');?> 
                            </div>
                            </div>                      
                        </div>
                    <?php }?>                    
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>      
        <!-- END: content -->

        <!-- BEGIN: footer -->
        <div id="yt_footer" class="yt-footer wrap">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END: footer -->
        <?php 
        if( Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home'  && 
                        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' && $var_yttheme->getParam('showPopup') == 1  ) { 
        ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('popup_location') ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>'
```

app\design\frontend\mypackage\mytheme\template\page\2columns-left.phtml

'

```
<?php
global $var_yttheme;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>

<?php 
    if( $var_yttheme->getParam('usebgimage') == 1 && $var_yttheme->getParam('usecustomizeimage') == 0 ){
        $bg_image = $var_yttheme->getParam('bgimage');
    }else{
        $bg_image = '';
    }

    $hdStyles = $var_yttheme->getParam('headerstyles');
    $classHeader = "";
    $classHome = "";
    if($hdStyles == 'header1'){
         $classHeader = "header1-wrap";  
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header2') {
        $classHeader = "header2-wrap";
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header3') {
        $classHeader = "header3-wrap";
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header4') {
        $classHeader = "header4-wrap"; 
    }
    if( Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home-v3'  && 
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' ) {
        $classHome = "homepagev3";
    }
?>

<body id="bd" class="<?php echo $var_yttheme->template ?> <?php echo $bg_image;?> <?php if( $var_yttheme->getParam('layoutstyle') == '2' ){echo "layout-boxed";}?> <?php echo $this->getBodyClass();?> <?php echo $classHome;?>">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <div id="yt_wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
        <!-- BEGIN: Header -->
        <div id="yt_header" class="yt-header wrap <?php echo $classHeader; ?>">
             <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END: Header -->

        <!-- BEGIN: content -->
        <div id="yt_content" class="yt-content wrap">           
            <div class="yt-content-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class ="row">
                        <?php if($this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs')){ ?>          
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <div class="columns-w">
                            <div id="yt_left" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="yt-left-wrap">
                                    <?php if( Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home-v3'  && 
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' ) { ?>
                                    <div id="yt-responsivemenu" class="yt-responsivemenu">
                                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mobiMenu2'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="yt-menu">
                                        <div id="btn_categories">
                                            <span><i class="icon-cate"></i><?php echo $this->__("Categories"); ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="yt-menu-content">
                                            <?php if( $var_yttheme->getParam('menustyle') == 'mega' ){
                                                echo $this->getChildHtml('megamenu-vertical-home');
                                            } else {
                                                echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu2');
                                            } ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                                            //menu more cate
                                            $i = 0;
                                            $('.sm_megamenu_wrapper_vertical_menu .sm_megamenu_menu').append('<div class="more-wrap"><span class="more-view"><?php echo $this->__("More Categories"); ?></span></div>');
                                            $('.sm_megamenu_wrapper_vertical_menu .sm_megamenu_menu > li.sm_megamenu_lv1').each(function(){
                                                $i ++; 
                                                if($i>11){ 
                                                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                                                }           
                                            });
                                            $('.sm_megamenu_wrapper_vertical_menu .sm_megamenu_menu .more-wrap > .more-view').click(function(){
                                                if($(this).hasClass('open')){
                                                    $i=0;
                                                    $('.sm_megamenu_wrapper_vertical_menu .sm_megamenu_menu > li.sm_megamenu_lv1').each(function(){
                                                        $i ++;
                                                        if($i>11){
                                                            $(this).slideUp(200);
                                                            //$(this).addClass('disappear');
                                                            //$(this).removeClass('appear');
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                    $(this).removeClass('open');
                                                    $('.more-wrap').removeClass('active-i');
                                                    $(this).text('More Categories');
                                                }else{
                                                    $i=0;
                                                    $('.sm_megamenu_wrapper_vertical_menu .sm_megamenu_menu > li.sm_megamenu_lv1').each(function(){
                                                        $i ++;
                                                        if($i>11){
                                                            $(this).slideDown(200);
                                                            // $(this).addClass('appear');
                                                             //$(this).removeClass('disappear');
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                    $(this).addClass('open');
                                                    $('.more-wrap').addClass('active-i');
                                                    $(this).text('Close Menu');
                                                }
                                            });                                        
                                        })
                                    </script>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div id="yt_main" class="yt-main-right yt-main col-main col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="yt_main_inner">                                 
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>

                                    <?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>  
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>                                                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Hot categories home page v3 -->
                <?php if( $this->getChildHtml('hot-categories') ){?>
                    <div class="hotcate-wrap">
                        <div class="container">
                        <div class ="row">                  
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('hot-categories');?> 
                        </div>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                <?php }?> 

             </div>
         </div>      
        <!-- END: content -->

        <!-- BEGIN: footer -->
        <div id="yt_footer" class="yt-footer wrap">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END: footer -->        

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>'
```

app\design\frontend\mypackage\mytheme\template\page\2columns-right.phtml

```
'<?php
global $var_yttheme;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>

<?php 
    if( $var_yttheme->getParam('usebgimage') == 1 && $var_yttheme->getParam('usecustomizeimage') == 0 ){
        $bg_image = $var_yttheme->getParam('bgimage');
    }else{
        $bg_image = '';
    }

    $hdStyles = $var_yttheme->getParam('headerstyles');
    $classHeader = "";
    $classHome = "";
    if($hdStyles == 'header1'){
         $classHeader = "header1-wrap";  
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header2') {
        $classHeader = "header2-wrap";
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header3') {
        $classHeader = "header3-wrap";
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header4') {
        $classHeader = "header4-wrap"; 
    }

    if( Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home-v2'  && 
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' ) {
        $classHome = "homepagev2";
    }

?>

<body id="bd" class="<?php echo $var_yttheme->template ?> <?php echo $bg_image;?> <?php if( $var_yttheme->getParam('layoutstyle') == '2' ){echo "layout-boxed";}?> <?php echo $this->getBodyClass();?> <?php echo $classHome;?>">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <div id="yt_wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
        <!-- BEGIN: Header -->
        <div id="yt_header" class="yt-header wrap <?php echo $classHeader; ?>">
             <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END: Header -->

        <!-- BEGIN: content -->
        <div id="yt_content" class="yt-content wrap">           
            <div class="yt-content-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class ="row">
                        <?php if($this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs')){ ?>          
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <div class="columns-w">                                                     
                            <div id="yt_main" class="yt-main-left yt-main col-main col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="yt_main_inner">                                 
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>

                                    <?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>  
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>                                                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="yt_right" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="yt-right-wrap">
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Hot categories home page v2 -->
                <?php if( $this->getChildHtml('hot-categories') ){?>
                    <div class="hotcate-wrap">
                        <div class="container">
                        <div class ="row">                  
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('hot-categories');?> 
                        </div>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                <?php }?> 
             </div>
         </div>      
        <!-- END: content -->       

        <!-- BEGIN: footer -->
        <div id="yt_footer" class="yt-footer wrap">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END: footer -->         

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>'
```

app\design\frontend\mypackage\mytheme\template\page\3columns.phtml

```
'<?php

global $var_yttheme;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>

<?php 
    if( $var_yttheme->getParam('usebgimage') == 1 && $var_yttheme->getParam('usecustomizeimage') == 0 ){
        $bg_image = $var_yttheme->getParam('bgimage');
    }else{
        $bg_image = '';
    }
?>

<body id="bd" class="<?php echo $var_yttheme->template ?> <?php echo $bg_image;?> <?php if( $var_yttheme->getParam('layoutstyle') == '2' ){echo "layout-boxed";}?> <?php echo $this->getBodyClass();?>">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <div id="yt_wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
        <!-- BEGIN: Header -->
        <div id="yt_header" class="yt-header wrap">
             <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END: Header -->

        <!-- BEGIN: content -->
        <div id="yt_content" class="yt-content wrap">
            <div class="yt-breadcrumbs">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="yt-content-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class ="row">
                        <div id="yt_left" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="yt-left-wrap">
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="yt_main" class="yt-main-right yt-main col-main col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="yt_main_inner">
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>

                                <?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>  
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>                                                                
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="yt_right" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="yt-right-wrap">
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>      
        <!-- END: content -->

        <!-- BEGIN: footer -->
        <div id="yt_footer" class="yt-footer wrap">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END: footer -->        

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>'
```

Answer (score 1):

These are called the global messages. They were add as a child in all  template layout files. So for changing the position of these global notices go to

`app/design/frontend/youpakacage/youtheme/template/page/1column.phtml`

and change these position of **global messages** block. mean move this code

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>`

same as go for other three template files.
`page/2columns-left.phtml`,`page/2columns-right.phtml`,`page/3columns.phtml`.

updated file

```
<?php
global $var_yttheme;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>

<?php 
    if( $var_yttheme->getParam('usebgimage') == 1 && $var_yttheme->getParam('usecustomizeimage') == 0 ){
        $bg_image = $var_yttheme->getParam('bgimage');
    }else{
        $bg_image = '';
    }

    $hdStyles = $var_yttheme->getParam('headerstyles');
    $classHeader = "";
    $classHome = "";
    if($hdStyles == 'header1'){
         $classHeader = "header1-wrap";  
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header2') {
        $classHeader = "header2-wrap";
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header3') {
        $classHeader = "header3-wrap";
    } elseif($hdStyles == 'header4') {
        $classHeader = "header4-wrap"; 
    }

    if( Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home-v4'  && 
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' ) {
        $classHome = "homepagev4";
    }

?>

<body id="bd" class="<?php echo $var_yttheme->template ?> <?php echo $bg_image;?> <?php if( $var_yttheme->getParam('layoutstyle') == '2' ){echo "layout-boxed";}?> <?php echo $this->getBodyClass();?> <?php echo $classHome;?>">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <div id="yt_wrapper">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?> //move here it will shown before header
        <!-- BEGIN: Header -->
        <div id="yt_header" class="yt-header wrap <?php echo $classHeader; ?>">         
             <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END: Header -->

        <!-- BEGIN: content -->        
        <div id="yt_content" class="yt-content wrap">

            <div id="yt_main" class="yt-main col-main">
                <div class="yt-main-inner yt-content-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class ="row">                    
                            <?php if($this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs')){ ?>          
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <div class="columns-w">



                            <?php if( $this->getChildHtml('banner-top-home') ){?>                   
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('banner-top-home');?>                            
                            <?php }?>

                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                    <!-- Hot categories home page -->
                    <?php if( $this->getChildHtml('hot-categories') ){?>
                        <div class="hotcate-wrap">
                            <div class="container">
                            <div class ="row">                  
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('hot-categories');?> 
                            </div>
                            </div>                      
                        </div>
                    <?php }?>                    
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>      
        <!-- END: content -->

        <!-- BEGIN: footer -->
        <div id="yt_footer" class="yt-footer wrap">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END: footer -->
        <?php 
        if( Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home'  && 
                        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' && $var_yttheme->getParam('showPopup') == 1  ) { 
        ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('popup_location') ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i didnt understand please explain in detail

Comment: you mentioned only this code   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?> this will display notice message but what about other messages?

Comment: ok. i have edit my question and please edit your answer in above file

Comment: this 1column.phtml file

Comment: i just want to display all messages on top of the page currently it display on middle of page. so please show me demo in this file i will update it in  other files

Comment: i update all files but still message displayed on middle of the page

Comment: i have refreshed cache but still not showing. for see output go to this link  [link](http://imgur.com/rjO2NMg)

Comment: yes i have edit this code in mytheme  file not default file

Comment: updated the code it was my mistake move this block `global_messages`.

Comment: is there is only need to move the globle_messages block?  Is no other changes is required?

Comment: @SwatiNehe no other changes required.

Comment: tried too much time but not working please provide me another  solution

Comment: disabled the cache and tried it again there is no other solution for that. try ti change the class name or edit something and check their is changing effect or not..

Comment: tired but not working

Comment: do you have live link of website or working on locale

Comment: only newsletter subscription success and error message displayed on top of the page all other (customer registration, login)  etc message display on middle of the page

Comment: did you change on all the layout file that i mention `app/design/frontend/youpakacage/youtheme/template/page/2columns-left.phtml`

Comment: yes i updated this changes in all files

Comment: please see my updated file and tell me which changes are required?

Comment: i see the change there is nothing to change here kindly go to `admin panel system >  configuration > (in left navigation) developer > debug (set scope to website)  > template path hint to yes` and check the file

Comment: tired to move the position of <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>      but not working for me. please suggest another